# What does 'normal' mean in random_normal() from tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Just one simple question.

I often mistype random_normal() to normal_random() and I just want to stop that.

So, what 'normal' means in this function?

Comment: It means the random values are sampled from a [normal probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). Newer versions of TensorFlow prefer the syntax [`tf.random.normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal), with all the distributions clearly grouped under [`tf.random`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random).

Comment: @jdehesa thank you!